# Dynamic SP returning values in reverse order

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using MS SQL and created one Dynamic stored procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_MTracking] 
(
@OList varchar(MAX)
)
    As
    BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(600)

    SET @SQL = 'select os.X,os.Y from Table1 as os join Table2 as s on os.sID=s.sID where s.SCode IN ('+ @OList +')'

    exec (@SQL)


    END TRY                                  
    BEGIN CATCH   
        Execute sp_DB_ErrorInfo
        Select -1 Result
    END CATCH

GO
```

It is working properly, but I am getting x,y values in reverse order.
For example if I am passing 'scode1,scode2' as parameter, I am getting x,y values for scode1 in 2nd row and x,y values for scode2 as first row.

How can I fix this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long for a comment.

SQL tables and results sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless you explicitly use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Your query does not have an `ORDER BY`.  Hence, you have no reason to expect the results in any particular order.  In addition, the ordering may be different on different runs of the query.  If you want the results in a particular order, add `ORDER BY`.

Probably the easiest way is to use `charindex()`:

```
order by charindex(',' + s.code + ',' , ',''' + @olist + ''',')
```

This is a bit more cumbersome in dynamic sql:

```
    SET @SQL = '
select os.X,os.Y
from Table1 os join
     Table2 s
     on os.sID = s.sID
where s.SCode IN (' + @OList + ')
order by charindex('','' + s.code + '','', '','''  + @OList + ''', '')
';
```

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds.  If only I could just type a few characters faster I could probably have a rep pushing 400k too.  Gave you my upvote, since finishing the post of what I was typing would make it look damn near like I was plagiarizing you now.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff,How can i order according to my parameter  list

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of things here.
The **first** thing is what Gordon wrote - to ensure the order of the result set you must use the `order by` clause.

**Second**, like Devart demonstrated in his answer, you don't need dynamic sql for this kind of procedures.

**Third**, if you want your results ordered by the order of the parameters in the list, you should use a slightly different approach then Devart wrote.
Therefor, here are my 2 cents:

If you can change the stored procedure to accept a [table valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `VARCHAR(max)` that would be your best option IMHO.
If not, you must use a [split function](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql) to create a table from that `varchar` and then use that table in your select.
Note that you will have to choose a split function that returns a table with two columns - one for the value and one for it's position in the original string.

Whatever the case may be, the rest of the sql should be something like this:

```
SELECT os.X, os.Y
FROM Table1 os
INNER JOIN Table2 s ON os.[sID] = s.[sID]
INNER JOIN @TVP t ON s.SCode = t.Value
ORDER BY t.Sort
```

That's assuming @TVP to be a Table containing a `Value` column that's the same data type of `SCode` in table2, and a `Sort` column (an int, naturally).

Answer (score 0):

Without dynamic sql -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MTracking]
(
    @OList VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @t TABLE (val VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON))
    INSERT INTO @t
    SELECT item = t.c.value('.', 'INT') 
    FROM (
        SELECT txml = CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(@OList, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML)
    ) r
    CROSS APPLY txml.nodes('/r') t(c)

    SELECT os.X, os.Y
    FROM Table1 os
    JOIN Table2 s ON os.[sID] = s.[sID]
    WHERE s.SCode IN (SELECT * FROM @t)
    --OPTION(RECOMPILE)

END
GO
```

Comment: While your point is valid and important, it doesn't answer the original question asked.